# Create DataBase Usign Jframe, Getting Exception Unknown DataBase Selection

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, swing, jframe

```
import java.awt.*;
public class MainWindow {
private JFrame frmMainwindow;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;
private JTextField textField_3;
private JTextField textField_4;
private JTextField textField_5;
private JTextField textField_6;
private JTextField textField_7;
private JTextField textField_8;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                window.frmMainwindow.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 * 
 */

Connection conn = null;
Connection conn1 = null;

public MainWindow() {
    initialize();
    MainPage mp = new MainPage();
    mp.setVisible(true);

}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
public void Reset(){
    textField.setText(null);
    textField_1.setText(null);
    textField_2.setText(null);
    textField_3.setText(null);
    textField_4.setText(null);
    textField_5.setText(null);
    textField_6.setText(null);
    textField_7.setText(null);
    textField_8.setText(null);
}

public void DBCreation(){
    conn = CreatingDb.CreateDb();
    String DBName = textField.getText();

    try{
        String query = "CREATE DATABASE " + DBName ;
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DB Created Successful.....");
        pst.close();

    }catch(Exception R){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, R);
    }
}

public void Insert(){

     String DBName = textField.getText();
    conn1 = SqlConnection.InsertDB(DBName);


    try{
        String Table1 = "CREATE TABLE PERSONALINFO (PersonName VARCHAR(25),DoorNO VARCHAR(10),Street VARCHAR(25),Village VARCHAR(25),PhoneNo LONGINT(10),UserName VARCHAR(15),Password VARCHAR(10),Hint VARCHAR(50))";
         String Insert1 = "INSERT INTO PERSONALINFO (PersonName,DoorNO,Street,Village,PhoneNo,UserName,Password,Hint) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement pstt = conn.prepareStatement(Table1);
        PreparedStatement psti = conn.prepareStatement(Insert1);

        psti.setString(1, textField_1.getText());
        psti.setString(2, textField_2.getText());
        psti.setString(3, textField_3.getText());
        psti.setString(4, textField_4.getText());
        psti.setString(5, textField_5.getText());
        psti.setString(6, textField_6.getText());
        psti.setString(7, textField_7.getText());
        psti.setString(8, textField_8.getText());

        pstt.execute();
        psti.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Table Created and Data Inserted Successfully....");
        psti.close();
        pstt.close();

    }catch(Exception R){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, R);
    }
}

private void initialize() {
    frmMainwindow = new JFrame();
    frmMainwindow.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frmMainwindow.getContentPane().setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
    frmMainwindow.setTitle("Create DataBase");
    frmMainwindow.setBounds(100, 100, 668, 416);
    frmMainwindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int height = screenSize.height;
    int width = screenSize.width;
    frmMainwindow.setSize(width/2, height/2);

    // center the jframe on screen
    frmMainwindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frmMainwindow.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel_1.setBounds(120, 70, 426, 205);
    frmMainwindow.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
    panel_1.setLayout(null);
    panel_1.setVisible(false);

    JLabel lblDatabaseName = new JLabel("DataBase Name");
    lblDatabaseName.setBounds(0, 3, 107, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblDatabaseName);
    lblDatabaseName.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JLabel lblPersonName = new JLabel("Person Name");
    lblPersonName.setBounds(0, 32, 89, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblPersonName);
    lblPersonName.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JLabel lblDoorNo = new JLabel("Door No");
    lblDoorNo.setBounds(0, 57, 79, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblDoorNo);
    lblDoorNo.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JLabel lblStreet = new JLabel("Street");
    lblStreet.setBounds(0, 85, 46, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblStreet);
    lblStreet.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JLabel lblVillage = new JLabel("Village");
    lblVillage.setBounds(0, 110, 46, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblVillage);
    lblVillage.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JLabel lblPhoneNo = new JLabel("Phone No");
    lblPhoneNo.setBounds(0, 135, 58, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblPhoneNo);
    lblPhoneNo.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JLabel lblUserbame = new JLabel("UserName");
    lblUserbame.setBounds(232, 3, 79, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblUserbame);
    lblUserbame.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
    lblPassword.setBounds(232, 32, 68, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblPassword);
    lblPassword.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JLabel lblHint = new JLabel("Hint");
    lblHint.setBounds(232, 57, 46, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblHint);
    lblHint.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(117, 0, 105, 20);
    panel_1.add(textField);
    textField.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
    textField.setColumns(10);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(117, 29, 105, 20);
    panel_1.add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setBounds(117, 54, 105, 20);
    panel_1.add(textField_2);
    textField_2.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
    textField_2.setColumns(10);

    textField_3 = new JTextField();
    textField_3.setBounds(117, 82, 105, 20);
    panel_1.add(textField_3);
    textField_3.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
    textField_3.setColumns(10);

    textField_4 = new JTextField();
    textField_4.setBounds(117, 107, 105, 20);
    panel_1.add(textField_4);
    textField_4.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
    textField_4.setColumns(10);

    textField_5 = new JTextField();
    textField_5.setBounds(117, 132, 105, 20);
    panel_1.add(textField_5);
    textField_5.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
    textField_5.setColumns(10);

    textField_6 = new JTextField();
    textField_6.setBounds(321, 0, 105, 20);
    panel_1.add(textField_6);
    textField_6.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
    textField_6.setColumns(10);

    textField_7 = new JTextField();
    textField_7.setBounds(321, 29, 105, 20);
    panel_1.add(textField_7);
    textField_7.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
    textField_7.setColumns(10);

    textField_8 = new JTextField();
    textField_8.setBounds(321, 54, 105, 20);
    panel_1.add(textField_8);
    textField_8.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
    textField_8.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnReset = new JButton("Reset");
    btnReset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Reset();
        }
    });
    btnReset.setBounds(232, 171, 89, 23);
    panel_1.add(btnReset);

    JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
    btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DBCreation();
            Insert();
             Reset();
        }
    });

    btnSave.setBounds(327, 171, 89, 23);
    panel_1.add(btnSave);
    panel_1.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]{lblDatabaseName, textField_1, lblPersonName, lblDoorNo, lblStreet, lblVillage, lblPhoneNo, lblUserbame, lblPassword, lblHint, textField_2, textField_3, textField_4, textField_5, textField_6, textField_7, textField_8, btnSave, btnReset, textField}));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel.setBounds(217, 122, 233, 101);
    frmMainwindow.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblCreateDatabase = new JLabel("Create DataBase");
    lblCreateDatabase.setBounds(0, 4, 120, 14);
    panel.add(lblCreateDatabase);
    lblCreateDatabase.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JLabel lblOpenDatabase = new JLabel("Open DataBase");
    lblOpenDatabase.setBounds(0, 42, 120, 14);
    panel.add(lblOpenDatabase);
    lblOpenDatabase.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Delete DataBase");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 82, 120, 14);
    panel.add(lblNewLabel);
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JButton btnNew = new JButton("New");
    btnNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            panel.setVisible(false);
            panel_1.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnNew.setBounds(144, 0, 89, 23);
    panel.add(btnNew);
    btnNew.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JButton btnSelect = new JButton("Select");
    btnSelect.setBounds(144, 38, 89, 23);
    panel.add(btnSelect);
    btnSelect.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));

    JButton btnRemove = new JButton("Remove");
    btnRemove.setBounds(144, 78, 89, 23);
    panel.add(btnRemove);
    btnRemove.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 14));
}
}
```

My Second java file

```
public class SqlConnection {

Connection conn1 = null;

public static Connection InsertDB(String DBName){
    String value = DBName;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String DB = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB+value,"root","");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,value);
        return conn;
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        return null;
    }
}


}
```

MY Third java File

```
public class CreatingDb {

Connection conn = null;

public static Connection CreateDb(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/","root","");
        return conn;
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

MY Forth java File..

```
public class MainPage extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainPage frame = new MainPage();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public MainPage() {
    setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    JMenuItem mntmNew = new JMenuItem("New");
    mnFile.add(mntmNew);

    JMenuItem mntmOpen = new JMenuItem("Open");
    mnFile.add(mntmOpen);

    JMenuItem mntmSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
    mnFile.add(mntmSave);

    JMenuItem mntmSaveAs = new JMenuItem("Save As...");
    mnFile.add(mntmSaveAs);

    JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    mnFile.add(mntmExit);

    JMenu mnEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
    menuBar.add(mnEdit);

    JMenu mnHelp = new JMenu("Help");
    menuBar.add(mnHelp);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
}
}
```

I Have imported required packages...
In the above code I am creating database using textfield at beginning of application. DataBase is created successfully but i am unable to access the created dataBase . It show java.sql.Exception: Unknown database Selection.
please any one help me ....

Comment: Shouldn't there normally be a schema on the connect string?

Comment: What i have to do now?

Answer (score 0):

```
 String DB = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB+value,"root","");
```

i think your problem appending. you do not append DB + value. give password.

Comment: i haven't given any password

Answer (score 0):

The [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) says this:

> If the database is not specified, the connection is made with no default database. In this case, either call the setCatalog() method on the Connection instance, or fully specify table names using the database name (that is, SELECT dbname.tablename.colname FROM dbname.tablename...) in your SQL. Opening a connection without specifying the database to use is generally only useful when building tools that work with multiple databases, such as GUI database managers.
>
> Note
>
> Always use the Connection.setCatalog() method to specify the desired database in JDBC applications, rather than the USE database statement.

It doesn't specify what happens if you don't call `setCatalog()` but given your problem I guess "nothing good."  You should add a schema to your connect string or call `setCatalog()`.

Comment: How to use setCatalog()